# PyQt5 Открыть форму в другой форме которые созданые в QT Design

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Создал две формы в `Qt Design`, конвертировал в `.py` файл.
Как теперь при нажатии клавиши в первой форме вызвать другую?

Comment: код предоставьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По сути, у нас есть два виджета, пусть будут: `MainWidget` и `Dialog`. И нам нужно просто создать и показать `Dialog`.

Если виджеты находятся в разных модулях (файлах `.py`), то либо их модули импортируются и через модули к виджетам обращаются, либо виджеты импортируются из модулей.

Покажу пример создания виджетов и показа одного виджета из другого:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Создадим виджет и сохраним ссылку на него
        self.dialog = Dialog()
        self.dialog.resize(200, 200)

        self.button_show = QPushButton('Show')
        self.button_show.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)

        self.button_hide = QPushButton('Hide')
        self.button_hide.clicked.connect(self.hide_dialog)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button_show)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_hide)
        layout.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def show_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.show()

    def hide_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.hide()


class Dialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = MainWidget()
    w.resize(200, 100)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]